# Pass clicked element's information to a modal as props - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I want access properties like id, etc of the clicked item on the modal. How can I pass target properties as props to modal on click.

Below is what I am trying. Unfortunately, the modal shows the targetElement prop as undefined in `componentDidMount` function of `CropperModal`

```
export default class DynamicArticleList extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(){
        super();
         this.state={
            
             targetElement: '',
            
             
        }
     
        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
        this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
 
    }
 
    showModal(e){
        
        this.setState({
            targetElement: e.target.getAttribute("id")
        })
    }
    
    hideModal(e){
        this.setState({
            showing: false,
            showSource: '#',
        })
        
    }
  

 
    


    render() {
      

        return (
       

            <div className="wrapper container-fluid DynamicArticleList">
                <div className="width-control">
                   <img src="../img/journey.jpg" onDoubleClick={this.showModal} id="Img0"/>
                   <CropperModal targetElement={this.state.targetElement}/>                   
                
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `img` element does not have an ID attribute assigned.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, my code is very complex so I simplified it here and forgot to add id but in my code id is there. BTW I edited the question.

Comment: You're waiting targetElement to appear in ComponentDidMount. if you have we same code as you attached then you render CropperModal from start and later you're adding targetElement to your state. You need to use ComponentDidUpdate or getDerrivedStateFromProps in CropperModal )

Comment: how does that change the scenario? @jamomani

Comment: I don't know `CropperModal` but perhaps passing the empty string to it is prohibited? If that's the case and that component normalizes the empty ID `''` to `undefined`, you might need to render it only under the condition that the `targetElement` is not empty: instead of directly writing `<CropperModal .../>` use `{ targetChosen &&  <CropperModal .../>}` with `const target = this.state.targetElement; const targetChosen = target && target !== '';` right before the `return ( ...)` in `render`. Maybe your `showing` prop is already there for this...

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` goes for a endless loop and eventually throws an error @boikov

Comment: @DeWySady Read comment of HeroWanders. He wrote the same idea in different way) It looks like you're rendering CropperModal before you have actual value

Comment: unfortunately not the case @HeroWanders. Assume everything is fine with `CropperModal`. Only problem is the, I am not able to pass the id of the element I clicked when I clicked

Comment: I have tried to reproduce it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-i6pgp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark -- seems to works fine.

Comment: Thanks, getting it on the same component works. Problem was to pass it to another component on click. The problem with modal was it rendered with render of the main class and there was no way to update the modal component again with updated properties. `ComponentWillUpdate` went to loop. Checkout my below answer, works like charm. I actually controlled the rendering of the modal component on condition. Now that component is getting rendered only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it. I basically avoided the modal component to render until the click event was processed

```
export default class DynamicArticleList extends React.Component {

constructor(){
    super();
     this.state={
         showing: false,
         targetElement: '',
        
         
    }
 
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);

}

showModal(e){
    
    this.setState({
        showing: true,
        targetElement: e.target.getAttribute("id")
    })
}

hideModal(e){
    this.setState({
        showing: false,
        showSource: '#',
    })
    
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper container-fluid DynamicArticleList">
            <div className="width-control">
               <img src="../img/journey.jpg" onDoubleClick={this.showModal} id="Img0"/>
               {this.state.showing ? <CropperModal targetElement={this.state.targetElement}/> : null}                  
            
            </div>
        </div>

    );


 }
}
```